# Pivot table averge by total number of months

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, average

I have an excel data table which have these colomns,
Purchae date
Item name
Quantity
Sipplier name
Now i want to get  average of quantity by total number of months.
I.e quanty sum is 50 and this is tenth month. So the average should be 5 per month.
More over this should keep updating as the month number go on.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Does your data contain some years of data, if not, please look down.

According to your description, I create a brief sample, then right click the data > Click **Get Data from Table/Range** to Power Query.

[image]

Click "Purchase date“ > Home > Transform > Data Type, set Date for it > Replace current.

Then go to Add Column > From Date & Time group > Date > Month > Name of Month.

[image]

And then go to Transform > Table group > Group By > Basic ---> "Month Name" (The column that you get from the step above) ---> enter a new name ---> such as "Month list" ---> Sum ---> Quantity ---> OK. After these steps, I get the result as following.

[image]

Click File > Close & Load To > PivotTable Report > Existing worksheet or New worksheet > OK.

Drag the "Month Name" to Rows, the "Month list" to Values, set the average function for it.

[image]